Swift 6 (not Swift 5) hits a breakpoint in libdispatch.dylib
My app has 2 targets, iOS and visionOS. It uses some Metal code for rendering.
If I compile it with Swift 5, rendering works as expected.
With Swift 6, rendering hits unexpectedly an internal breakpoint:

This happens for iOS and visionOS, for the simulators and the devices.
Apparently, code that is executed to run on a certain queue is executed on another queue. The only queue related to Metal in my code is a MTLCommandQueue.
I guess this is a bug in the library, but I am of course not sure.
Is there anything I can do to get the code running?

I had this problem with a call to NSItemProvider and had to give up on that call. Luckily I was able to find a different call that didn't elicit this crash. You are correct that this is an issue in Apple's own code and you should report it to Apple immediately. See also https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%25sblock+was+%25sexpected+to+execute+on+queue&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

I found the instruction that does not work under Swift 6 (I should have done this earlier, sorry).
My app uses a PerspectiveCamera in a RealityKit entity.
Currently there is bug in RealityKit (confirmed by Apple) that does not allow to use the output of an additional PerspectiveCamera directly. Instead, one has to use a RealityRenderer.
To its property entities, a PerspectiveCamera can be appended. Its output is rendered to a MTLTexture. It can be assigned to the metalLayer of a UIKit UIView, which is then displayed as a UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI.
A RealityRenderer has a function updateAndRender that renders its entities including the output of a PerspectiveCamera, see here.
This function works under Swift 5, but hits the internal breakpoint under Swift 6, before the handler onComplete is called.
So I guess this is a bug in RealityKit, and I will write a bug report.

If you have any calls to addCompletedHandler, try adding @Sendable to the closure. See https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/763909.

I don't have a call to addCompletedHandler...

How about addScheduledHandler or anything else that might take a closure? Can you try to get a more complete crash log?

@ReinhardMänner – Also, the MTKViewDelegate methods are isolated to the main actor. If you are using this protocol, you need to make sure that your implementations are isolated to the main actor, too. This question is exceedingly difficult to answer without a MRE. But this sort of error generally stems from incorrect isolation (the referenced Metal-specific sendability issues notwithstanding).
